# Как сконвентировать файл xlsx в tiff python

Tags: python, excel

Суть проблемы в следующем:

1. Пишу скрипт для себя, который сможет конвертировать xlsx в tiff, в интернете нашел много примеров, но для windows с использованием win32com. Я использую MacOs(поиски для аналога не увенчались успехом).
2. Пробовал unocovn, получается конвертировать в формат pdf(через терминал), и потом в формат tiff(НО буквы съезжают, и результат плачевный конечно)

Подскажите,каким инструментом можно решить данную проблему, неделю уже бьюсь над этим.

---

Пример ожидаемого результата.

Слева полученный файл в формате tiff(через онлайн сервисы), справа сам эксель файл

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем это? Вы каждую ячейку таблицы в виде пикселя представляете?

Comment: Или хотите скриншот?

Comment: Налоговая принимает документы в электронном виде в формате tiff.Пользоваться онлайн сервисами не очень хочется, 
Скриншот совсем не то, https://a.radikal.ru/a27/2011/33/1b617f4f144d.png 
Слева полученный файл в формате tiff(через онлайн сервисы), справа сам эксель файл

Comment: Спасибо, не знал про такое... извращение :) Пробовали https://github.com/glexey/excel2img ? Интересно, им нужен именно tiff, или хватит, например, png, который назовут tiff

Comment: Да пробовал( Там необходим модуль py32win( Они принимают только tiff (именно с 2 *ff*).

Comment: Или тут: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60182972/5909792 используйте такой импорт: `import os` `import win32com.client` `from PIL import ImageGrab`

Comment: Спасибо большое, за активную помощь, неожидал что так с энтузиазмом будут помогать. Но win32com.client это же модуль для windows или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Блин... точно у вас ведь MacOs... Извините, привык, что большинство вопросов тут с виндой. Мб попробуйте на винде те скрипты и если будет успешно можно будет поднять виртуалку с виндой и там, например, сделать сервис (в виде простенького вебсервера), на который пошлете xlsx, а в ответ получите tiff. Еще вариант для Mac, можно попробовать отправить документ на печать и посмотреть что выйдет, если сработает, то использовать виртуальный принтер, который как картинку вернет документ

Comment: Ничего страшного) Сам еще не до конца привык к мировозрению MacOS. Я находил данные ответы с похожей рекомендацией на просторах иностранных форумов. Но так как,тямки на это не хватает, мне кажется этот вариант тяжелым для меня. Естесвенно я больше склоняюсь к тому,что выход есть, просто я не умею правильно искать ответ в интернете. Вот и решил задать вопрос знающим людям...

Comment: Так как у вас форма, то вы можете вручную сделать задачу влоб, вам нужно а)распарсить excel б) взять графический шаблон и наполнить его информацией. Вопрос 1) вы хотите что бы всю задачу сделала библиотека? 2) нужно распарсить, вы ищите библиотеку что бы распарсить, а рендеринг вы делаете руцями 3) вы хотите и парсить и рендеринг сделать?

Comment: Я хотел бы просто автоматизировать данный процесс, чтобы запустить написанный скрипт, который прочитает данные из одного эксель файла(в котором возьмет данные) ,внесет их в данную форму (скрин справа) и на выходе по завершению скрипта даст заполненный файл в формате tiff. Это конечно идеальный вариант для меня. Тока не знаю в какую сторону мне капать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение только костылем, сначала переводить ексель файл с pdf с помощью unoconv(нужна установка или libre office, или Open Office), потом poppler+pdf2image в tiff.